# How can I compile a 32bit program and run it on a 64 OS system such as Windows 7?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a program compiled in Visual Studio 2005 in an x86 System (32-bits), but when I try to run it in x64 OS (64-bits  Windwos 7, Windows 2003, Windows 2008) it doesn't execute, I only get the following message:

```
 "myapp.exe has stopped working
 Windows is checking for a solution to the problem... "
```

I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package for 32 and 64bits both(vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe) on the execution machine but the application still doesn't run.

I have also changed the option on the Development machine in the Configuration Manager Window to generate from 'Any CPU' to 'x86' platform, with the same result.

Is there any other configuration option, dll, lib, or package that allows to compile myapp in 32-bit and execute in 64-bits?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Eugin.

Comment: what about making this community wiki? It might be a diffuse issue (I still have winXp)

Comment: @BlackBear, not appropriate.  A 32 bit application should run on a 64 bit cpu/os.  If there was some process involved, it might be appropriate, but in this case, there is something wrong with the posters application.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to recompile your program to run on a 64bit OS, there is some other bug that is causing it to crash.